# Find if array contains item if exists returns that item both array are json object list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to find an item in an array which is from another array. But the inner for-loop is executed as per counts. But I need to check if an item exists and if it does, return that item. How to achieve this in jQuery. Here's what I coded so far.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var UserInfo = names[i];
  $("td.text-center", row).html('');
  var date;
  var dt = designationHistoryList;

  for (var j = 0; j < dt.length; j++) {
    if (UserInfo.employeeIcode == dt[j].employeeIcode) {

      $("td", row).eq(0).html(dt[j].designationHistoryIcode);
      $("td", row).eq(1).html(UserInfo.employeeDisplayName);
      var designationNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ListofDesignations"));
      for (var k = 0; k < designationNames.length; i++) {
        if (dt[k].designationIcode == designationNames[k].designationIcode) {
          $("td", row).eq(2).html(designationNames[k].designation);
        }
      }
      date = new Date(dt[j].designationEffectiveDate);
      $("td", row).eq(3).html(date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2));
      if (HasUpdate() == true) $("td.text-center", row).append('<a href="#" onclick="GetEmpDetails(' + dt[i].designationHistoryIcode + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit User" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>');
      if (HasDelete() == true) $("td.text-center", row).append('<a href="#" onclick="ConfirmDelete(' + dt[i].designationHistoryIcode + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete User" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>');

    }

  }

  $("#example-datatable").append(row);
  row = $("#example-datatable tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps pushing to `dt` in your `Logics here`? Please post your (full) input and desired output

Comment: I have added full logic code now

Comment: I'm trying to find an item in the second array if exists means I need to returns it by means of using that, I have written the if() part logics there.

Comment: better using forEach for loop and Array.find() for finding the target item in an array. even better write demo to reproduce your problem, then you can get help more easily.

Comment: It only returns the first element Array.find() But I need all matched elements any other suggestions to achieve this? @Pengcheng

Comment: You can use Array.filter(), that returns an array matching your condition